# GLEW can't find GL version

Tags: opengl, sdl-2, glew

According to the error output GLEW cannot find the GL version. I'm running the latest Nvidia drivers for my 660s.

Here's the interesting bits of my code:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum glewErr = glewInit();

if(glewErr != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't init GLEW" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << glewGetErrorString(glewErr) << std::endl;
}

// Create main window
GLWindow mainWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL");

//Test GLEW
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
std::cout << vertexBuffer << std::endl;
```

The program crashes at the GLEW test. Console says it can't find the GL version. Rest of the code is [here](https://github.com/2bdkid/OpenGL-Stuff)

Comment: Create a GL context before you initialize GLEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jozxyqk said, I had to create a GL context before I initialized GLEW.